# Como eliminar colunas sem títulos e dados no dataframe criado a partir do Openpyxl

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

Transformei o objeto Openpyxl (pasta_quimica), criado a partir de uma planilha, em um Dataframe.

```
# Transforma objeto openpyxl em DataFrame
dados = pasta_quimica.values
cabecalho = next(dados)[0:]
df = pd.DataFrame(dados, columns=cabecalho)
```

No dataframe pandas aparecem duas colunas no final, sem dados e sem título. Qual a melhor maneira de eliminar estas colunas, no Openpyxs ou no Pandas?

[Resultado da conversão do objeto Openpyxl em dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpvsA.png)

Comment: Tende o drop. Mais ou menos assim: `novo_df = df2 = df.drop(df.columns[[-2, -1]],axis = 1)`. Nao tenho certeza que indice negativo funciona... Qualquer coisa, pegue o numero de colunas com `len(df.columns)` e depois coloca os indices...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Abaixo os dados foram obtidos de um arquivo de log, e as colunas vazias foram removidas.

```
df = pd.read_table('log_file.txt', sep=';')

#Remove empty column
for column in df:
    if 'Unnamed: ' in column:
        df.drop(columns=[column], axis=1, inplace=True) 

df.columns = ['Folder','File','Hour','Channel','Command','Art']
df.to_excel('Sheet.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False)
print('Finished!')
```